# Final Fantasy $1$ has been released today?

Tags: situation, mystery

I had a friend in my school who used to hate studies . He always liked to play video games, studying nothing, always talks about video games in school, and also gets some scolds from the teacher. Surprisingly, in every exams , he used to score full marks, being one of the toppers in school !! .

Our final exams were coming near, and I thought that I have to study everyday.

So one day I asked my friend, "Hey, will you come at my house tonight? We will together study for our final exams."

He said, "No way, dude. Final Fantasy $1$  has been released just today, I am ditching school tomorrow so that I can buy it and play."

I didn't know what Final Fantasy $1$ is, as I was not that interested in games and always working with my study-books. But I couldn't still understand how he could get full-marks in every exams , where even I couldn't.

Finally I got tired and asked him, "How can you get full marks in every exams without even studying anything, and by just playing video games? What is your secret?"

He replied with a smile, "I am a psychic . I can read the future and see the every exact questions that will come in the exam."

For a second, I almost believed him. But he said, "No no, I was just joking."

In the final exams, he again scored full marks.

Is he really a psychic? or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that

> He is either psychic, or at least very confident of the games success.

This is because

> He refers specifically to Final Fantasy **1**. However, on release (back in 1987) it is just known as Final Fantasy. Including the "1" implies that he knew more will come. It would be a bit like referring to "The Great War" as "World War One" before 1939.

Comment: Correct Answer and Explanation !!